# Objects not displaying when I change Z coords (OpenGL)?

Tags: c, opengl, perspectivecamera

I'm having a problem when rendering in OpenGL. Everything displays fine, until I change the Z coord, it gets clipped/it's out of view! Is that what's happening? Am I setting up my perspective projection matrix wrong? I'm stumped...

Relevant bits of my rendering code (the `mat4_` funcs are an external library, and are similar to their GL friends).

```
vec3_t eyevec = vec3_create(NULL);
eyevec[0] = 0.0f;
eyevec[1] = 0.0f;
eyevec[2] = 0.1f;
vec3_t centervec = vec3_create(NULL);
centervec[0] = 0.0f;
centervec[1] = 0.0f;
centervec[2] = 0.0f;
vec3_t upvec = vec3_create(NULL);
upvec[0] = 0.0f;
upvec[1] = 1.0f;
upvec[2] = 0.0f;

vec3_t transvec = vec3_create(NULL);
transvec[0] = 0.0f;
transvec[1] = 0.0f;
transvec[2] = -2.0f;

mat4_t perspective = mat4_perspective(60.0f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f, NULL);
mat4_lookAt(eyevec, centervec, upvec, perspective);

mat4_t modelview = mat4_identity(NULL);
//mat4_translate(modelview, transvec, modelview); objects vanish when doing this!
mat4_multiply(perspective, modelview, perspective);

const GLfloat verts[] = {
   //verts
   0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
   0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
   0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
   //colors
   1.0f, 0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f,
   0.5f, 0.1f, 0.4f, 0.3f,
   0.0f,  1.0f, 0.5f, 0.6f,
   0.0f,  1.0f, 0.5f, 0.6f,
   //tex coords
   0.0f, 0.0f,
   0.0f, 1.0f,
   1.0f, 1.0f,
   1.0f, 0.0f,
};

const GLushort indices[] = {3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1};

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, NULL);
```

Also note that I've tried translating in both positive and negative directions.

Comment: What are you changing it from/to?

Comment: Check your `near` / `far` ranges.

Comment: @mihai maruseac: mat4_perspective(60.0f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f, NULL); sets the near to 0.1f, and the far to 100.0f

Comment: And the z coordinate you're changing?

Comment: @mihai maruseac: vec3_t transvec = vec3_create(NULL);
transvec[0] = 0.0f;
transvec[1] = 0.0f;
transvec[2] = -2.0f; mat4_translate(modelview, transvec, modelview); (It's the commented out line)

Comment: Try setting `eyevec[2]` to a higher value such as `3` or `5`.

Comment: @oskar: that doesn't work either. This is really frustrating and it makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

The near as you commented is 0.1f, and while translating you are setting z : transvec[2] as -2.0f.

so it is before the near plane, that means it will be rendered behind your eye in world space.

This seems like why its disappearing.

Comment: But it disappears when this value is set to either positive or negative.

Comment: @Shokwav I always set my perspective as :  viewFrustum.SetPerspective(35.0f, float(len)/float(wide),1, 5000)